# Balance load between CPU and GPU

Tags: optimization, gpu, unreal-5, cpu

I am making a game with Unreal Engine 5, but it takes more GPU power and the CPU is used much less.

I want to optimize it to use both CPU and GPU so it can be playable on low-end PCs or laptops. Is there a way I can shift some of the rendering load to the CPU?

Comment: Hey there, this question is currently too vague to be answered. The more high level tools you use, the further away you get from the hardware, so it might be difficult to specifically control what each piece of hardware does with a game engine. Having said that, the general approach is to make your game, and once it's finished, use profilers to optimise it more and more until it's playable on the hardware of your choice, no matter how low-end it is.

Comment: You're unlikely to achieve what anyone would call "optimizing" your game by moving work from GPU to CPU. The reason that work is being sent to the GPU is that the GPU is much better at that workload than the CPU. Moving it to the CPU, where that's even possible, will tend to make your game performance *worse* because the CPU will be slower at doing that job, since it lacks the massive parallelism that lets the GPU crunch so many vertices/pixels all at once. Instead, what you should do is run a profiler to determine what the most expensive GPU work is, and ask how to reduce that load.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, but I voted to close as "needs more focus". Some games could be inherently CPU or GPU bottlenecked.